Trying to open the Sprite files from Cookie Shop DS with Python 3.x
I’m trying to rip all of the Cookie Shop DS character sprites by using Python. I already got pypng installed but I don’t understand saving as “cookie2png.py”, It’s too hard for me too do.
Can you help me what to do with the sprites on Python?
Here’s the link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fxNnJelt-tJbpN40otoYPNp6o0vpHQoh

I’m voting to close this question because it is a work request for a specific system, not really a question

but I don’t understand ... why are you not asking about that?

because it's from the folder structure. I'm not very good at python coding though

Already solved here: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24742/trying-to-rip-the-sprites-of-this-game
